# QuiltView failed to instantiate

Tags: android, android-layout

all library and resource are attached with the github quiltView sample project but it cannot not run. 
But error like:

```
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979): java.lang.VerifyError: com/jake/quiltview_lib/QuiltView  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  
05-27 15:30:18.675: E/AndroidRuntime(10979):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
```

please help me . I need such type of output. if there is another way to display that output please help me.

sample project is in :

https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary#dependencies

please help!

Comment: I'm sure people would agree that they are not really interested in the library code you are trying to add to your project, but they would like to see actual code where and how you are using it in your project to be able to better understand what is going on